# Jquery selector with name apply to multiple names

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery name selector and apply to multiple names. How can I achieve that ? Here is what I kind of want to do.

```
$("select[name='name_xx name_yy']").domystuff...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [starting with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('select[name^="name"]')
```

If they are different names then use a comma to separate the selector as @MilindAnantwar:

```
$('select[name="name_xx"],select[name="name_yy"]')
```

Comment: name_xx and name_yy was just for reference. they will not actually start with word name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use multiple selector:

```
$("select[name='name_xx'],select[name='name_yy']").domystuff..
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i wanted to use not selector for multiple, could you help ?
Something like 
$("select:not[name='name_xx'],select:not[name='name_yy']").domystuff..

Comment: You need attribute not equal to selector. `$("select[name!='name_yy']")`